# Expanding linux partition failure

Tags: linux, partitioning, parted

I'm puzzling over a very simple task. I have an img file which contains a filesystem with 2 partitions.
As found in some tutorials I expanded the available space in this way:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./temp_image bs=1 count=1 seek=3G
cat temp_image >> orig_image.img
losetup --offset [offset of the second partition*512] /dev/loop0 orig_image.img
e2fsck -f /dev/loop0
resize2fs -f /dev/loop0
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

But I'm afraid the partition table is not resized correctly:

```
parted orig_image.img > print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/user/orig_image.img: 7255MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  67,1MB  62,9MB  primary  fat16        lba
 2      67,1MB  4000MB  3933MB  primary  ext4
```

But if I chroot into the system it actually finds new space...
Was I miss some steps?

I tried to resize the partition using gparted but it fails complaining about errors during e2fsck.

Comment: running e2ksck on /dev/loop0 fails with error in the super-block magic number

Comment: FWIW, better not use `parted`, for it uses SI unit instead of binary unit by default, which can cause confusion. use `fdisk -l` instead.

Comment: Also you need to resize the partition (entry on the partition table) before you resize the filesystem with `resize2fs`.

Comment: FIY this is the link where I find that dd command (second answer): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4943/resize-image-file-before-writing-to-sd-card

Comment: Never mind. I was wrong. The command does create an image with 3GiB sparse file + 1 byte zeros. `truncate -s 3G image_for_append` is still better anyway though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend `truncate` instead of quirky `dd` command that creates 3GiB sparse file + 1 byte zeros. `truncate` use sparse file as well. With `-s 3G` you get a image of precisely 3GiB sparse file with no zeros (or you can use `count=0` for `dd` too):

[image]

I prefer doing it "in-place" with `truncate`, since `cat` would convert the sparse file to zeros (although that might be what you want), which costs time, space, and excessive write.

The following example does it "in-place" (see the `+` prefix between `-s` and `3G` in the `truncate` command):

[image]

As you can see, **you need to resize the partition** (e.g. with `fdisk`) **as well**. So you need to use `losetup -P` instead of just attaching the partition by specifying an offset. This is what you've missed since the solution you linked/quoted *applies to a filesystem image only*.

When you recreate the partition entry after deleting the original one, make sure it starts at the same LBA as the original (in the example it's `206848`), otherwise the filesystem will be lost.

Comment: I successfully accomplished my needs with your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never tested the described way, but if your deal with an SD-Card, the following works for me.

1. `dd` the image unchanged to the sdcard with `dd if=my.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M`
2. `sync` after that
3. Use `fdisk` to `d`elete the `2`nd partition. Then create a `n`ew partition and accept all defaults. Then `w`rite the partition table.
4. `sync` again
5. Check the filesystem with `e2fsck -f /dev/mmcblk0p2`
6. Resize the fs with `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2`
7. `sync` again

Comment: Thanks but I need to manage the partitions BEFORE burning the sd-card. I need to do all the stuff with the img file. In detail I want to expand the second partition (ext4) and then create another ext4 partition after that.